# A differential equation and coordinate geometry problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-geometry

> If the normal drawn to a curve at any point P intersects the x-axis at G and the perpendicular from P on
> the x-axis meets at N, such that the sum of the lengths of PG and NG is proportional to the abscissa of
> the point P, the constant of proportionality being k. Form the differential equation and solve it to show
> that the equation of the curve is,
> $$y^2=cx^{\frac{1}{k}}-\frac{k^2\cdot x^2}{2k-1}; \text{ or }y^2=\frac{k^2\cdot x^2}{2k+1}-cx^{-\frac{1}{k}}$$
> where $c$ is an arbitrary constant

What I did was pretty simple: I drew a diagram and then used the formula for the tangent($PG=y \csc(\theta)$), subtangent($y\cot(\theta)$) and subnormal($y\tan(\theta)$)(where $\tan(\theta)=y'|_P$) and I was left with this DE

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{y'}\cdot y +(y'+\frac{1}{y'})y=kx\\ \Rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{y'}\cdot y +(\frac{1+y'^2}{y'})y=kx$$

I am pretty much stuck at this point, I got to an answer but it didn't match the answer and I figured it was all wrong anyway due to a mistake at the beginning. There are no standard forms that I can see which lead to simpler solutions.

---

EDIT: Many are saying that $\tan(\theta)\neq y'$ but I have by definition defined that $y'=\tan(\theta)$.Here's the type of diagram I have in mind

[image]

Comment: I just have had a look at your figure with what you call $\theta$. Why not $\theta$ for this angle ? **But the problem is that** : I think you misinterpret "the perpendicular from P on the x-axis" as being the tangent. If such had been the case, the authors of this exercise would have said the "tangent to the curve" ; for me it's clear, "the perpendicular from P on the x-axis" is the perpendicular that you draw orthogonal to the $x$ axis... with $G$ having the same abscissa as $P$.

Comment: Oh yes! I think I got it now. I'll check if I can get to the result now. Thanks, @Jean Marie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with your definition of $\tan(\theta)$ and it should be as Jean Marie mentioned above.

The differential equation that you need to solve is

$$|y|\sqrt{1+y'^2}+|yy'|=kx$$

Note that the lengths of $PG$ and $NG$ are non-negative.

I will consider the case $y,y'>0$. We have

$$y\sqrt{1+y'^2}+yy'=kx$$

Squaring both sides and using that $\sqrt{1+y'^2}=\frac{kx}{y}-y'$ we have

$$y^2\left(y'^2+1+y'^2+2y'\sqrt{1+y'^2}\right)=k^2x^2$$
$$y^2\left(1+\frac{2y'kx}{y}\right)=k^2x^2$$
$$2yy'kx+y^2=k^2x^2$$
$$2yy'+\frac{1}{kx}y^2=kx$$

Now substitute $u=y^2,du=2yy'dy$

$$u'+\frac{1}{kx}u=kx$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be the orthogonal projection of  $P$ onto the $x$ axis, and $\theta $ := polar angle of $GP$.

I agree with your equation that I prefer to write under the form:

$$\dfrac{y}{\sin \theta}+\dfrac{y}{\tan \theta}=kx \tag{1}$$

But after that I disagree because

$$\tan \theta = - \frac{1}{y'}$$

(a classical formula)

Besides, as $$\sin \theta = \dfrac{|\tan \theta|}{\sqrt{1+(\tan \theta)^2}}$$

(please note the use of absolute values), we obtain  the following differential equation:

$$|y|\sqrt{1+y'^2}+yy'=kx$$

Comment: I think $\tan(θ)$ was by definition y' according to how I defined it. Yeah, θ is the polar angle of GP. Can you show what your differential equation comes out to be and then at least give a hint to solve it?

Comment: I could do that but, first of all, you have to convince yourself by drawing a piece of curve (for example decreasing) around P to see that the slope of the tangent is negative so you cannot have $y'=tan \theta$.